# How to limit parameters passed using Dapper's DynamicParameter constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

Using the Dapper DynamicParameters constructor, is there a way to exclude certain parameters from being included? For example, say I have the following entity,

```
public class EntityA
{
    public string Method1 { get; set; }
    public string Method2 { get; set; }
    public string Method3 { get; set; }
}
```

And I am calling a stored procedure that only has Method1 and Method2 as parameters, can I have the DynamicParameters method only pass the those two parameters and skip the third parameter?  For my live example, I have a lot more properties for my entity and would rather use an exclude scenario than specify parameter by hand.

Comment: Can I ask: what is the reason for DynanicParameters in this scenario? If you simply pass in your EntityA as the parameters object, it will already be automatically filtered to the things it thinks are used in the SQL (as long as it is CommandText)

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by passing EntityA as parameter object?

Comment: `conn.Execute("update SomeTable set name=@name where id=@id", obj)` where obj is an EntityA instance - will only send .Id and .Name

Comment: I am using stored procedures for all of my database access, CRUD operations.  How does the provided example work in that scenario?

Comment: indeed; in that scenario it *does not* attempt to filter the properties; that, then, is the answer to "what is the reason...?". Can I ask: of the members present, how many will be redundant? My concern is that you end up moving a lot of overhead to the "which members to project" code...

Comment: My entities represent the database tables and I have certain stored procedures that say may only need 34 of 39 property values for a save operation.  While other procs may need everything.  There are alot of properties in several of the entities and I may only need to exclude 5 or 6 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option here is an anonymous projection - this can be done for either the argument object itself, or to the parameter to `DynamicParameters` if you need to add additional custom parameters; for example:

```
conn.Execute(sql, new { obj.Foo, obj.Bar });
```

or:

```
var args = new DynamicParameters(new { obj.Foo, obj.Bar });
// not shown: add some more custom parameters
conn.Execute(sql, args);
```

Comment: In this scenario, I would add an entry for each member I would like to add to the DynamicParameters object?  Look like this is the way to go, though that is going to be a large DynamicParameters declaration :-).

Comment: @user1790300 well, do you propose something better? either it is opt-in, or opt-out; without tangible sql (sproc names don't count), it is hard to see how it could be anything else

Comment: Duly noted.  I guess I could write a utility that could generate the DynamicParameters based upon the DeriveParameters method.  That way maybe I could only add parameters that are there.  My concern would be efficiency however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension method like the following to generate dynamic parameters.  In a case like mine, where i have a Large number of parameters, it saves a little time.

```
public static class ParameterExtensions
{
    public static DynamicParameters ConvertToDynamicParameters<T>(this T incoming)
    {
      DynamicParameters dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
      foreach (PropertyInfo property in incoming.GetType().GetProperties())
      {
        object value = GetPropValue(incoming, property.Name);
        if (value != null) dynamicParameters.Add(property.Name, value);
      }
      return dynamicParameters;
    }

    private static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
      return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName)?.GetValue(src, null);
    }
}
```